# Python numpy dataframe conditional operation (e.g. sum) across two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate a conditional sum that involves a lookup in another dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
first = pd.DataFrame([{"a": "aaa", "b": 2, "c": "bla", "d": 1}, {"a": "bbb", "b": 3, "c": "bla", "d": 1}, {"a": "aaa", "b": 4, "c": "bla", "d": 1}, {"a": "ccc", "b": 11, "c": "bla", "d": 1}, {"a": "bbb", "b": 23, "c": "bla", "d": 1}])
second = pd.DataFrame([{"a": "aaa", "val": 111}, {"a": "bbb", "val": 222}, {"a": "ccc", "val": 333}, {"a": "ddd", "val": 444}])

print(first)
print(second)
```

The two DataFrames are

```
     a   b    c  d
0  aaa   2  bla  1
1  bbb   3  bla  1
2  aaa   4  bla  1
3  ccc  11  bla  1
4  bbb  23  bla  1
```

and

```
     a  val
0  aaa  111
1  bbb  222
2  ccc  333
3  ddd  444
```

I want to append a column in `second` that has the sum of column `b` in `first` in which `first.a` matches the corresponding `second.a`. The expected result is:

```
     a  val result
0  aaa  111      6
1  bbb  222     26
2  ccc  333     11
3  ddd  444      0
```

Note that this is a minimal example and I'd ideally see a generalizable solution that uses lambda or other functions and not a specific hack that works with this specific example.

Comment: Why should it use lambda rather than pandas/numpy methods?

Comment: Good point @roganjosh - I don't care what functions it uses as long as the solution is generalizable. I just edited the OP correspondingly.

Comment: Fair enough. The reason I picked up on it is that generally lambda will make code slower as it'd be used in `apply` or similar, which will usually break vectorization. Not always, but generally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) then use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the result of groupby.

```
g = first.groupby('a')['b'].sum().rename('result')
result = second.merge(g, on='a', how='left').fillna(0)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
     a  val  result
0  aaa  111     6.0
1  bbb  222    26.0
2  ccc  333    11.0
3  ddd  444     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work. (came late...)

```
temp = first[['a','b']].groupby('a').sum().rename({'b':'result'}, axis = 1)
df = pd.merge(second, temp, left_on='a', right_index=True, how ='outer').fillna(0)
```